# php- Getting Country code for calling on mobile based on ip

Tags: php, geolocation, ip

Is there any way To Detect Country code for calling on mobile of user using his/her ip address?

Actually I'm trying that for sending `SMS` on clients device. For Sending password recovery to their mobile if requested, For that I log their country code based on their IP at time of `sign up`.

But even if I've their Country saved in my DB and also `IP` catched by `php` script, I am unable to convert that information to their country code.

ex.

I've Info Like:

`IP: 127.0.0.1 //Just for ex.`

`Country: Chile`

`Mobile: XX88XX99XX`

Then How can I get Country code for that specific country Here in this case `+056`, `+001` for US. For Sending SMS to that mobile number?

Is it possible in php?

If So, How?

Can Experts here please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$data = file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip);
$data = json_decode($data);
echo $data->geoplugin_currencyCode;
```

See more here: http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp Don't use it with 127.0.0.1 or localhost because it will send 127.0.0.1. [Here](http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=186.120.118.215) is an example with my IP.

Comment: I don't need currency code, I need country code for making international call.

Comment: @user3571968 have you found an appropriate API yet?